# Internet connection speed when connected to sensor that has Ethernet interface

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, network, ethernet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I am connecting a LIDAR called UST-20lx to my computer using a Ethernet cable. To do that I have modified `/etc/network/` interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet static
address 192.168.0.14
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
metric 800
```

I am able to get the LIDAR data using the official `urg_node`. However, when I was connected to the LIDAR, the internet speed decreased dramatically. For example, I have to wait 30+ second to get into ROS wiki. However, the internet speed seems fine when I go to google and even youtube (no problem watching youtube videos).

Here are my ifconfig:

```
enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:01:2e:78:1d:00  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:df200000-df220000 

enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:01:2e:78:1d:01  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:100 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:10692 (10.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:320 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:320 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:27150 (27.1 KB)  TX bytes:27150 (27.1 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:f8:62:80:c6:27  
          inet addr:192.168.0.11  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2600:8806:3200:d340:90f6:8f12:42e4:9da/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::cca4:6183:8d81:7c0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8985 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4291 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9437491 (9.4 MB)  TX bytes:985890 (985.8 KB)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296579/internet-connection-speed-when-connected-to-sensor-that-has-ethernet-interface/) by [Kolohe113](https://answers.ros.org/users/36311/kolohe113/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2018-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the wifi and wired interface would have had the same gateway defined which might be causing problems.  You can try removing the `gateway 192.168.0.1` line on the lidar network interface, you don't need that.

Google and youtube work fine since you're accessing them through IPv6.

---

Originally posted by [kartikmohta](https://answers.ros.org/users/524/kartikmohta/) with karma: 308 on 2018-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kolohe113](https://answers.ros.org/users/36311/kolohe113/) on 2018-07-08**:
I removed the gateway line and the problem still exist. Can I add a IPv6 line in /etc/network/interfaces to boost the speed?